# WiX - How to declare global variables in WiX bundle?

Tags: wix, bundle

I am writing a WiX bundling project which involves two MSIs. My requirement is to declare a "global variable" in the Bundle context, so that it can be referenced anywhere in the wxs files of any of the two MSIs.

Is there a possible way to accomplish this?

P.S. I am building the project in WiX v3 using Visual Studio extension.

Answer (score 2):

Declare a variable in the bundle and pass it to the msi's

For example in the bundle:

```
<Variable Name="InstallFolder" Type="string" Value="[ProgramFiles6432Folder]$(var.Manufacturer)\[WixBundleName]"/>

<MsiPackage Id="Product" SourceFile="$(var.Product.TargetPath)">
     <MsiProperty Name="INSTALLFOLDER" Value="[InstallFolder]" />
</MsiPackage>
```